# What does "32KB (16K x 16)" mean?

Tags: flash-memories

On digikey site program memory for **[ATMEGA328P-AU-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0/ATMEGA328P-AU-ND)** is shown as **32KB (16K x 16)**. in ATMEGA328P [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_summary.pdf) program memory is 32KB but what does **(16K x 16)** mean?

Other Examples are :

- 16K x 8
- 64 x 16
- 64K x 8
- 1K x 16

Comment: x16(b) =2B because B=8b

Comment: "16K x 16" is just nonsensical information here. There is no 16 bit organization of the memory whatsoever in the 8 bit AVRs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

16K means 16,384 'storage locations' of 8 bits, thus 16KB.
64 x 16 means 64 storage locations of 16 bits, thus 128 (8 bit) bytes.

The example you give for the Atmega is thus 16,384 times 16 (bits) is 32,768 (8 bit) bytes.

Normally the 'B' in KB is Byte, which is 8 bits, however due to the hardware layout memory sometimes is layout in 16 bits.

Comment: 16 **KiB** (**Ki**bi**B**ytes) is 16,384 bytes. Just saying.

Comment: @HarrySvensson True, however, in practice you see everywhere KB meaning 1,024 bytes instead of the metric unit K = 1,000 bytes

Comment: Small or caps matters with units: k (small k) means 1000. K (caps K) means Kelvin. Some people even insist of confusing s (seconds) and S (Siemens = 1/Ω). In the very early days, people in the RAM chip industry decided to have a prefix "K" meaning 1024 in contrast to the standard "k" meaning 1000. This was present everywhere.

Comment: @HarrySvensson, it's not microsoft it's industry in general. Except for harddrives, for all microcontrollers kb refers to 1024. Be it in RAM, ROM, or whatever. Same applies to RAM discs and what not

Comment: If one means 1024 bytes, it has to be KB (old standard) or KiB (new standard). All others simply don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: Everyone has used "k" to mean 1024 (in computing) for donkey's years, except for HDD manufacturers whose marketing departments prefer 1000 (makes the drive sound bigger). The only people I know who've adopted this silly sounding kibibyte thing are obsessive compulsives on wikipedia. 1000 is a useless number to work with in binary, so it is common practice to expect 16k to be 16384, etc. A kibibyte sounds like some kind of cutesy pet food.

Answer (score 2):

It means there are 16k addressable locations, each of which is 16 bits or 2 bytes. So, 16kx2 is 32k. You have 16384 possible addressable locations, each of which holds a 16 bit number.